# another phrase to express dwelled on

Tags: expression-choice

After the incident he dwelled on the issues surrounding the incident.

What would be other substitutes to express the idea conveyed by "dwell on?"

I considered "mull over", "ruminate", "moped about", etc., but these terms don't communicate the thinking at length about something negative, a frustrating aspect of the term "dwell on." Some of these are too formal or don't have association with the negative frustrating nature of the event.

Comment: harp on:
to talk or write about to an excessive and tedious degree.

Comment: You could have considered ***dwelt on*** as a credible alternative to the question in your title. But you've obviously misunderstood the expression - it means *to **express one's thoughts** at length and/or exclusively on one particular subject* (in a speech or discourse involving an audience). That's not at all the same thing as *thinking long and hard* about something (*mull, ruminate*, which would normally be a *solitary* activity).

Comment: I think it's Unclear what OP is asking for here, since ***dwell on X, mull X over,*** and ***mope about X*** all mean significantly different things, and it's not obvious to me which of those (or which *other*) sense OP wants top convey.

Comment: ^ the comments are not entirely true. The post usage is in line with the received meaning of "dwell on" expression. This is its meaning from the Webseters: a :  to keep the attention directed —used with on or upon <tried not to dwell on my fears>
b :  to speak or write insistently —used with on or upon <reporters dwelling on the recent scandal>

Comment: @FumbleFingers As well as the definitions you've given; **Dwell on/upon**, does indeed mean, to think about. It does in my dictionary at least.

Comment: @JoeBlack **Brood** is a good alternative. **Seethe** might work as well, depending on the context.

Comment: @Joe: I take your point, but note that OED says ***now, esp.** to treat at length or with insistence, in speech or writing*.

Comment: Typical AmE usage includes thinking. - AmE speaker

Answer (score 4):

[**Brood**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brood) would work perfectly with what you're describing because it implies both length and negativity. Merriam Webster defines it this way:

> Brood (verb): to think a lot about something in an unhappy way

Answer (score 3):

Check if [*lingered* (over)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/linger) appeals to you.

> After the incident he *lingered over* the issues surrounding the incident.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps *[chewed over](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/chewed-over)*

> (transitive, adverb) to consider carefully; ruminate on

*Collins*

Also *[agonize](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/agonize)* (usually with *over*)

> Undergo great mental anguish through worrying about something

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Answer (score 1):

[Cogitated](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cogitated?s=t) works well here.

1. to think hard; ponder; meditate:

If that does not express enough negativity then you could use, from BrEng, the verb ["obsess"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/obsessed?&o=100074&s=t) as in, "He obsessed about..."

2. to worry neurotically or obsessively; brood

Answer (score 0):

A different angle which highlights the insidious aspect, if applicable:

> The circumstances surrounding the accident kept [creeping up](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/creep+up) on him/her.

Answer (score 0):

If the negativity is anger - 'to seethe'

Google defines 'to seethe' as:

> (of a person) be filled with intense but unexpressed anger.
>   "inwardly he was seething at the slight to his authority"

A more mild term - 'to stew'

Again, Google gives us:

> worry about something, especially on one's own.